# Error handling in Mikrotik scripts

Tags: scripting, mikrotik

I have RouterOS 5.14 on RB493G. I need to write script, that launches

```
/tool fetch ...
```

Execution of fetch may result in error, this is OK(URL may be sometimes unavailable). Script hangs on error. Is there any way to ignore it?

---

Solution:

```
[admin@Mikrotik] >> /system script
0 name=safe-fetch source=
:global done
:global url

/tool fetch $url
:Set done=true

1 name=test source=
:global done
:global url="google.com"

:set done false
:execute safe-fetch
:local counter 0
:while ( $done != true && $counter < 10 ) do={
    :set counter ($counter+1)
    :delay 0.2
    }

if ($done = "true") do={
   :put "Fetch OK"
   } else={
   :put "Fetch ERROR"
   }
```

Warning: not documented ":execute" is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [there isn't error handling](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=54640) in this kind of scripts. You should probably adopt the solution proposed by [this guy](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=54640#p278349):

> So you have to have 2 scripts, one that runs and does stuff and handles situation when some value is not received as expected, and other script does the job, that can fail. as a result, if second script fails, first one that called second script to do the job will continue.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Mikrotik scripts are very poor and crooked :(

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 6 hours." - the bounty will be yours tomorrow.

Comment: I've added :delay to reduce processor load with empty cycle

Answer (score 10):

## UPDATE as of RouterOS v6.2

You can now create a `do` block with an error handler:

```
:do {
  /tool fetch $url
  :put "Fetch OK"
} on-error={ :put "Fetch ERROR"};
```

Comment: Finally, they added error handling. Thank you, @Old-pro !